# Scoping rules in operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Considering the following code:

```
namespace myNS {
class MyClass {

//.....
};
} //end of namespace myNS


using namespace myNS;

//overloading of '<<' operator
std::ostream &myNS::operator<<(std::ostream &os, MyClass &c){  /*....*/ }
```

In the last line, why is `&myNS::` needed?

Comment: Just to point out the `&` belongs to the `std::ostream`.

Comment: What is `Complex`, and where does it live?

Comment: Please post **real** code. `Complex` isn't defined anywhere. Was it supposed to be `MyClass`? And where it this `operator<<` defined?

Comment: Whoops, `operator<<` is defined in the snippet. But the `myNS::` says that it's defining an `operator<<` that was declared in `namespace myNS`, although there's no such declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is needed because, conventionally, streaming operators return a reference to the stream to allow them to be chained:

```
stream << something << something_else;
```

with `something_else` being passed to the stream reference returned by `stream << something`.

`myNS::` is needed if this operator is supposed to be scoped inside the namespace, in which case there must also be a previous declaration inside the namespace. If you want the operator to be in the current namespace (presumably the global namespace in this example), then it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, MyClass&)` is not declared inside the `myNS` namespace, there is no need to qualify it. This equivalent code is legal:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Foo
{ 
class Bar{}; 
}

using namespace Foo;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Bar&) { return o;}

int main() 
{
  Foo::Bar b;
  std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```